# Store geolocation users in database

Tags: php, ajax, html, geolocation

I am trying since some days to figure out what is wrong with the codes that I find here similar to my problem. Until now I didn´t success with mine.

Here is the code:

```
        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            function successFunction(position) {
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude
                                },
                        url: 'template-userslocation.php'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

and here the code in 'template-userslocation.php':

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Template Name: template-userslocation
    */

        echo $lat = $_POST['lat'];
        echo $lng = $_POST['lng'];


    ?>
```

And this is what I get back when I load the page:

> Notice: Undefined index: lat in .../template-userslocation.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: lng in .../template-userslocation.php on line 9

There is code before this that could make that it don´t works.
NOTE: I´ve added this after seeing that there seems be no mistakes in the first code and after getting some help from you guys.

That´s the code before:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                            var pos = {
                                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                lng: position.coords.longitude
                            };

                            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                            infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
                            map.setCenter(pos);
                     },

                function() {
                            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                    }); 

    } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            };
```

I think the `var pos = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};` is one of the problems that I have.

NOTE: Here all the code:

```
<div class="map">
    <div id="map"></div><!-- #map -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAp9iQ2oC3PEvy20_6aDpAPGLT8sFDqAjI&libraries=geometry,places&signed_in=true"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', gmaps_results_initialize );

        function gmaps_results_initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map' ), {
                zoom:           3,
                center:         new google.maps.LatLng( 28.291564, 16.62913 ),
                mapTypeControl: true,

                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
                },
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
                },

                scaleControl: true,
                streetViewControl: true,
                streetViewControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
                },
                fullscreenControl: true,
                fullscreenControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
                }
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

            <?php  if (is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

                       // Try HTML5 geolocation.

                       if (navigator.geolocation) {                         
                           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                               var pos = {
                                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                                  lng: position.coords.longitude
                               };

                               infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                               infoWindow.setContent('You are here');
                               map.setCenter(pos);
                           },


                           function() {
                               handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                           }); 


                     } else {
                            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                     };  

                     if (navigator.geolocation) {

                           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                               var coords = position.coords;
                               $.ajax({
                                   type: 'POST',
                                   data: {
                                       lat: coords.latitude,
                                       lng: coords.longitude
                                   },
                                   url: 'template-userslocation.php'
                               });

                           });
                    }

        <?php } else; ?>                
        } 

    </script>
</div>
```

What I´m doing wrong? In the other questions that I found similar, they also didn´t resolve it at all.

---

SOLVED:

The problem is that it is being made in Wordpress and Wordpress has his own way to handle AJAX.

[Here the info](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX)

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to verify if you're getting what you think you're getting.

Comment: Examine the post as it leaves the browser - usually you press the F12 key to do this.

Comment: I get array(0) {}. And in the console there are no errors.

Comment: Changed POST with GET. Same errors.

Comment: In your `successFunction(position) {}` add before AJAX call: `console.log(position.coords);` and see what you get? This could be that coordinates are empty.

Comment: Ok, there should be the problem. Because I get nothing in the console.

Comment: but `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)` is good because I get in `infoWindow.setPosition(pos);` the user position in the map.

Comment: maybe it has to do with your site not being in a secure context (https). [Note: As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: yes it is in https. I think the problem comes because I called the `lat` and  `lng` in a `var pos` in a code before. But don´t know how to fix all the code together.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got the URL wrong, look:

```
url: 'template-users-location.php'
```

There is a '-' after users. but you say your filename is template-userslocation.php

Comment: If that was the case, the POST would not go to the file and would not create notices...

Comment: Thak you. But in archive it's correct. I made the mistake writting it here. Thank you anyway! The problem still exists. :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around the data object members in your ajax request as such:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
         lat: position.coords.latitude,
         lng: position.coords.longitude
      },
      url: 'template-userslocation.php'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `function successFunction(position) {` never gets called.
However, after small modifications, this is how it will work, and pass the correct variables in the POST.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var coords = position.coords;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        lat: coords.latitude,
        lng: coords.longitude
      },
      url: 'template-userslocation.php'
    });

  });

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I´ve tried what you told me without success. It has to be any mistake in my way to write the code in. Is this correct? `echo $coords = $_POST['coords'];` The conditional that you wrote me I´ve put it after the if conditional with the `var pos`. All is inside the function `function gmaps_results_initialize()`

Comment: And I get this in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
    at (index):459`